# One drive menus are gone, anyone knows what happened to menu commands missing?

Tags: onedrive

[image: Menus of onedrive web interface are gone!]

Anyone knows what happened to the onedrive menus they are suddenly gone!

Comment: They look fine to me. What browser/OS are you using? Are you using any sort of Ad blocker?

Answer (score -1):

yes it seems a browser issue, why google and microsoft are so fuzzy about supporting each other.. it works in IE and not in chrome ver 39.0.2

Comment: another noticable and strange behaviour by onedrive, the menus and all command show in incognito mode in chrome but not in regular browsing mode. What a classic Microsoft workaround :-)